# How to find internship or supervisors if not in academia?

Tags: phd, independent-researcher, internship, research-proposal, networking

I don't have a MSc in STEM, however I gained some professional **experience** in data-science, but **outside of academia:**

- I coauthored a data-model at my former **startup**, described in a patent application that to date is cited 90+ times ;
- I coauthored a peer-review research collaboration with a research institute

Thing is, I got passion and would like to extend research on the data-model above and uptake relevant skills ( artificial intelligence on graphs ), mostly with a **motivation** for both applied research (spin-off, entrepreneurship, tech transfer).

I crafted research proposal for a **PhD**: however, since I don't have an MSc in a relevant field (required for a PhD in Europe), it's unlikely I may have a chance and I also would be very much content to break down the research proposal in simpler parts, and work on one for a peer-review publication.

I tried very hard to find a **supervisor** : a research **collaboration** would be ideal (i.e. one where I may 'trade' complementary skills for applied research, like UX or software development, or any other thing I may work at to get a temporary paid collaboration or a paid internship).

I also tried to offer myself as volunteer, to receive supervision in the prospect for being coached on a peer-review paper.

However, I could not find any researcher/professor who may want to allocate time, because I am not affiliated to any university and could not justify resources.
I also tried to inquire researchers in private sector, but **internships** are allowed only for students, and I am not.

Do you have suggestions to help find paid internship for non-students, or researchers who may be interested in offering supervision ?

My current situation is Im looking for job: I would be happy for temporary collaborations in research, also entry level, where I could gain skills and exchange ideas on my research interest.

Comment: If your long term goal is to have a PhD, you should be looking to finish a masters if you are staying in Europe. This sounds like a diversion.

Comment: Long term goal may be a PhD, OR applied research (starting a company or a spin-off, by using results of research into a service). I am no more in 20s @Buffy : possibility to 'save time' by matching paid opportunities with up taking up research skills in collaborations would be beneficial for me, and more instructive than MOOC courses.

Comment: What is a UX?  Is it anything an academic research would care about?

Comment: @TerryLoring UX = User Experience. Im interested in natural phenomena related to (let me be naif) how 'information emerges from chaos'. In a less naif way, I am interested in network science and skills as deep learning on graphs for research on how economics networks processes sustainability (I wrote a research proposal) as well as for applicability in other fields to study natural phenomena with numerical approaches: computational sustainability; cognition; decoding communication signals in ethology. I am more attracted to use UX and "product skills" for creating products on top of research.

Comment: Lol :) "it may happen only once per decade". I tried the route of connecting and proposing things on linkedin, and the route of proposing things to speakers met at conferences, and the route of proposing to researchers and professors at universities. A few, in a frank fashion, told - I appreciate your enthusiasm, but there is no more the time when one can just follow own interest. You must have titles to be eligible for grants, even if you are the one procuring the grants for the University must justify the allocation. So I tried to put a question here.

Comment: "Do not quit your day job yet" Im looking ! And that's why I put in the question, I'd be available also for paid internship. My 'strategy' would be : if I can create some publications background, I may have changes for being eligible for a PhD; a chance to reach out to a network (beyond the courtesy of linkedin but no concrete follow up unless there is an institution or money justifying the time invested in an 'independent researcher') and maybe more credibility to apply for grants or assemble a team, might there be results strong enough for a tech protoype.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo tks. Have you got a linkedin ?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119621/find-supervisors-when-not-in-academia